# Devise - Automatically delete account that hasn't been confirmed after a defined period of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Everything is in the title, I want to be able to **delete account that hasn't been confirmed after a set period of time**.

I'm using:

- Rails 3.0.5
- Devise 1.3.4

My Devise `User` model has these attributes:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

And my `db/schema.rb`

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "email",                                 :default => "", :null => false
    t.string    "encrypted_password",     :limit => 128, :default => "", :null => false
    t.string    "reset_password_token"
    t.timestamp "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.timestamp "remember_created_at"
    t.integer   "sign_in_count",                         :default => 0
    t.timestamp "current_sign_in_at"
    t.timestamp "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string    "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string    "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.timestamp "created_at"
    t.timestamp "updated_at"
    t.string    "confirmation_token"
    t.timestamp "confirmed_at"
    t.timestamp "confirmation_sent_at"
  end
```

Little bonus - in my `User` model, I've specify the relationships between my data, such as:

```
has_one  :user_content,     :dependent => :destroy
```

I want to make sure that its children are also deleted.

Thanks a lot for anyone who can help !

---

Thanks to **jrdi**, here's the answer for a database with **SQLite 3**

```
desc "Delete all unconfirmed users after 7 days"
task :delete_unconfirmed_users => :environment do
  users = User.all(:conditions => 'confirmed_at is NULL AND confirmation_sent_at <= datetime(\'now\',\'-7 days\')')
  users.each do |user|
    user.destroy
  end
end
```

For **PostGRE** (Heroku)

```
desc "Delete all unconfirmed users after 7 days"
task :postgre_delete_unconfirmed_users => :environment do
  users = User.all(:conditions => 'confirmed_at is NULL AND confirmation_sent_at <= current_date - integer \'7\' ')
  users.each do |user|
    user.destroy
  end
end
```

See his answer for full details.
Thanks@lot to him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a rake task that runs with a daemon, cron for example.

In this rake you can get all not confirmed users (`:confirmed_at` is `nil`) and get when send the confirmation email `:confirmation_sent_at`

When you have a users that conforms the especifications make `user.destroy`and all should be deleted correctly.

If you need a example of this rake task tell me and I make your first aproximation.

--- Edit ---

Create a delete_unconfirmed_users.rake in lib/tasks

```
desc "Delete all unconfirmed users after 7 days"
task :delete_unconfirmed_users => :environment do
  users = User.all(:conditions => 'confirmed_at is NULL AND confirmation_sent_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day)')
  users.each do |user|
    user.destroy
  end
end
```

Run `rake delete_unconfirmed_users`

Comment: Thanks! And yes, if you could give me an example of what I should write, I'll be grateful!

Comment: I edit my answer with a little example, I don't test it but I think that can be useful to you.

Comment: I had to remove the last "end". I remove the X and replace it by 7 but I get this error: SQLite3::SQLException: near "7": syntax error: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (confirmed_at is NULL AND confirmation_sent
_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day))

Comment: The problem was with SQLite and the SQL Query. I edited my question with the 'correct' answer for SQLite. Thanks a lot, your answer was really useful !

Comment: Ok I supposed that your are using MySQL, sorry. And I forgett tell you that needs replace the X with your "days" value.

Comment: One other change I made is the `>=` becomes `<=`. But it works perfectly. Thanks again ;)

Comment: I know it's an old answer, but I've just used `User.where("confirmed_at IS NULL").where('confirmation_sent_at < ?', Time.now - Devise.confirm_within)` with rails 4 and devise 3.5.